# Batch file dir command

Tags: windows, batch-file

ok, sry if the question will get little clumsy, but i dont know how else to give you information for you to be able to help me. 
I need to write a batch file to be able to do several tasks. Here is the whole code i've written:

```
@echo off  
:pasirinkimas  
cls  
echo Spauskite 1, jei norite pakeisti ekrano ir teksto spalva  
echo Spauskite 2, jei norite isvesti i ekrana sistemos kintamuosius  
echo Spauskite 3, jei norite ieskoti failu  
echo Spauskite 4, jei norite baigti darba  

set /p pasirinkimas= Iveskite psirinkima:   

if %pasirinkimas% == 1 goto Spalvos  
if %pasirinkimas% == 2 goto Kintamieji  
if %pasirinkimas% == 3 goto Paieska  
if %pasirinkimas% == 4 goto pabaiga  
goto pasirinkimas  

:Spalvos  
echo 0 = Black        A = Light Green  
echo 1 = Blue         B = Light Aqua  
echo 2 = Green        C = Light Red  
echo 3 = Aqua         D = Light Purple  
echo 4 = Red          E = Light Yellow  
echo 5 = Purple       F = Bright White  
echo 6 = Yellow  
echo 7 = White  
echo 8 = Gray  
echo 9 = Light Blue  

set /p fonas= Pasirinkite fono spalva:   
set /p tekstas= Pasirinkite teksto spalva:  
color %fonas%%tekstas%  
goto pasirinkimas  

:Kintamieji  
set  
:loop  
echo Ar norite testi darba (t/n)?:  
set /p darbas=  
if %darbas% == t goto pasirinkimas  
if %darbas% == n goto pabaiga  
goto loop  

:paieska  
echo iveskite ieskomo failo pavadinima:  
set /p ieskau=  
dir %ieskau%  
pause>null
goto pasirinkimas  

pause>null  

:pabaiga  
exit
```

So i need help with third function. Searching for files. Though i have @echo off at the very beggining, when im trying to look for a file, the screen displays unneeded text no matter if the file was found or not:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.  
Volume Serial Number is DEB6-826F  
Directory of "displays directory the batch file is in"
```

What i need is:
1. if batch finds the file im searching for that it would display the file size (which it does + first 2 unwanted lines).
2. When it doesnt find the file im looking for i need the batch file to display the message of my choosing.
How do i achieve this?

as far as my limited starter knowledge goes, @echo off should have dealt with volume messages. 
tried changing **dir %ieskau%** line with **dir /b /s  %ieskau%** line but that displays only file directory. I need that + file size.

(i hope im clear enough on what i need. Tried to be as clear as possible and give all the information possibly needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited**

```dos
if exist "%ieskau%" (
    dir /a-d "%ieskau%" 2>nul | findstr /r /c:"^ .*:\\.*" /c:"^  [ ]*[1-9]"
) else (
    echo File not found
)
```

If the indicated file exist, retrieve information, else show error.

The `dir` output is filtered by `findstr` using two regular expressions (`/r`): the first one will match the line with the folder name (the only that starts with a space and contains the string `:\`) and the second one will match the line with the file size (starts with two or more spaces followed by a digit between 1 and 9)

Comment: um.. thanks for reply. tried replacing my dir line with urs. what i get when file is found is:
**10/01/2015   02:35  PM                 700   2lab.txt**
date and time (not even today's) then 700 is a file size and a name of the file i was looking for

Comment: @NulisDefo, Sorry, this is what I think you were looking for. If not, which of the lines in the output of the `dir` command do you want?

Comment: 1. when i find the file (aka enter the existing file name e.g. 2lab.txt in my case) i need the output to show the directory of the file found and the size of the file found   
2. when i dont find the file i need the output to display "File not found" (or any other text. i think it should somehow go with echo. i think)

Comment: @NulisDefo, answer updated. Check if this gives the intended output

Comment: during the time till ur answer i kind of got to the same solution. just without the filtering of info. didnt manage to apply findstr properly. my version of command line was: if exist %ieskau% (
dir %ieskau%
) else (
echo Failas nerastas
)

Comment: though i dont understand the **2>nul** part. where does that come from?

Comment: `2>nul` means redirecting stream handler `2` (STRERR) to the `nul` (null) device, in other words, error messages are suppressed; this avoids any `File Not Found` messages of the `dir` command...

Answer (score 0):

you could brobably do something like;

```
Cd C:\
if not exist "*%ieskau%*" goto none
dir /s /b "*%ieskau%*" >C:\myfile.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (text.txt) do set c=%%i
echo these are your files %c%
exit /b
:none
echo no file found.
exit /b
```

But you will have to let it load for about 10 seconds (while its searching) also /b is optional, it just makes it look better...

hope that helps...

Comment: why `Cd C:\` though? i need to search for file in current directory in this case. and why  *%ieskau%*  ? first time i see an **if** subject to go not in between qoutes but like this

Comment: (how do i write a code in grey backgroun in comments? usin `code` dont work)

Comment: The CD C:\ brings you to the root of your computer. you could also do 
CD C:\users\%username%\    and that would search for files in your account only. the %ieskau% is just for no reason. i saw the last user do it. I'm assuming you earlier did something like;  set /p ieskau=FILE NAME:_    and then you can call what the user set ieskau as with %ieskau%. you can replace it with whatever you want though. Finally quotes should be included in the if statement. I forgot about that. i usually work in one word responses so i don't use them. for responses with spaces you should include quotes.